# texhash: command not found

Tags: packages, texlive, ubuntu

I'm trying to manually install a package on ubuntu, but neither the `sudo texhash` nor the `sudo mktexlsr` command is found by the terminal.

`which texhash` returns `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/texhash`, so it's there. Do I have to somehow "install" the command?

Comment: You probably have not added `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux` to the `sudo` `PATH`, it is not the same as the users `PATH`. Try running it as absolute path, ie `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/texhash`

Comment: That worked, though it's not a permanent solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that you have a 32-bit linux version. You have to add-paste the following lines to your `bashrc`.

```
#################################################
#                                               # 
#           LaTeX path configuration            #
#                                               #
#################################################

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/i386-linux
```

To do that open `bashrc` using the following command(without `$`)

```
$ gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Save the file and then in a terminal type(without `$`)

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Alternatively you can add the above lines in `.profile` using

```
$ gedit ~/.profile
```

Then type the following command in terminal(without `$`)

```
$ sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr
```

Now you should be able to run `tlmgr` and `sudo tlmgr`

Comment: Please don't ask people to add this to `bashrc`, this only covers command line. If you start an editor, say, TeXmaker from a menu, it will not be able to find LaTeX as it does not start a bash shell. Add it to `.profile` instead.

Comment: @Thanos @daleif That's the weird thing. I'm using vim, and I added `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux:$PATH` to my `.bashrc` ages ago, and my `.profile` looks like it just redirects to `.bashrc` and `bin`, if present (which they are). 
So, I really don't know why it's not finding texhash. 
Also, for future reference, should this have gone in Ask Ubuntu instead of the TeX Exchange?

Comment: @triested : Try to use `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux`. I assume that you have 32-bit ubuntu...